# why firefox is creating double cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies

My site creates two cookies after login, lets say:

```
$_COOKIE['a'] = 100;
$_COOKIE['b'] = 200;
```

I also sets this two cookie values to sessions:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = 100;
$_SESSION['b'] = 200;
```

So, it creates these values in firefox browser:

```
mysite.com PHPSESSID
mysite.com a
mysite.com b
```

But sometimes, I can see that it (firefox) is creating double cookie values with different PHPSESSID. So I can see:

```
mysite.com PHPSESSID
mysite.com a
mysite.com b
mysite.com PHPSESSID
mysite.com a
mysite.com b
```

Do you have any idea why firefox is creating these double cookies, even in running browser (without closing the window/tab)?

Comment: Maybe because different pages create new cookies?

Comment: could not understand your answer, if pagea.php creates $_COOKIE['a']=100 & $_COOKIE['b']=200 and pageb.php creates $_COOKIE['a']=300 and $_COOKIE['b']=400, will this pageb.php store these 300 or 400 values separately or it willl just override the value of a & b cookies created by pagea.php?